# Old home— removing and installing new switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, fans

I’m installing new fans in a home that is quite old. This includes exchanging all the switches wired onto the wall plates.
I’ve run into some very old wiring and some very old switch boxes — some of which I can’t get to trigger the release (see pic). Any recommendations?
My thought is that I’ll have to cut the wiring and remove some sheathing to attach. Would be a hell of a job to run new wiring to the wall plate. Help!

[image]

Comment: Can you pull the switch a little further out of the wall to get a picture of the back of it? Do bear in mind [JACK's cautions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/256268/34147) about possibly damaging this very old fabric insulation. You might have to angle your cell phone around to get a picture instead of moving the switch too much more.

Answer (score 4):

**If** you are not going to give up and put the switch back in, and you haven't managed to develop a technique to *release* the wires that works (try different tools that fit the release slots, try pushing in various ways) then **destroy** the old switches to **preserve wire length.**

They appear to be Bakelite® or similar phenolic plastic. Crush them with large slip joint pliers or locking pliers (or a C-clamp) and then remove the metal bits left on the wires, without the plastic housing you were going to dispose of in your way. Set a trash can under the switch before you start, and have a vacuum or dustpan and broom handy for anything that misses the trash can. Set the metal aside for scrap/recycle, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

You can try grabbing the bare wire with a needle nosed pliers and twisting the switch while pulling the wire. I'm guessing if there were slots in the back like backstabs, you would have put in a small screwdriver and pushed down to release the wire.

It will normally be a fairly big job to run new wire. You've have to trace the circuit to see where is goes and check that junction box to see if the wire's in better condition to splice to. If you have attic access, this job might be easier. If not, then you'll be cutting holes in the wall. The problem with this fabric covered wire is that once you start messing with it, the insulation can start to crack,exposing more of the wire conductor and can travel up past the box and behind it,possibly causing arcing and fire.

Comment: Good cautionary advice, however, it doesn't actually answer the question of how to get the wire out of the switch. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan  Good point... forgot the question when I saw that old wire. It's never a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

Wire length is precious. If you really cannot get those wires released then snip as close to the switch as possible.

It looks like you'll have enough length remaining to wire-nut a short length of hot and neutral which will be used for your new switch.

To avoid further fraying of the insulation you *could* use something like 3M 2234 Cable repair kit to keep it safe.